# Beginning a sentence with 'At'

Tags: grammaticality

I've been writing a scientific paper in English, although this isn't my native language and some colleagues have pointed out I could not start a paragraph with "At this paper..."
Can anyone elaborate on why for me?

Comment: You should perhaps include the phrase in context because there could be situations where "at this paper" would be correct.

Comment: You totally can start a paragraph with "at". In this case you must start it with "in", though. In English, things are *in* a paper, not *at* a paper. It's not that you can't start a sentence with "at this paper". It's that you can't say that at all.

Comment: If you’re describing what the paper aims to do, the standard phrase is “***In*** this paper, I will…”.

Answer (score 3):

Sentences can start with "At". However, the choice of preposition seems wrong in this example.  You would normally say "In this paper..."

> At five o'clock, tea was served in the conservatory.

At implies a time or location. In implies contained within the body of this work

> In this paper, we analyse the consumption of infusions of *Camellia Sinensis* among the descendants of the Anglo-Saxons.

Comment: *At* implies a time or location.  *In* implies contained within the body of this work.